# Why is flash being phased out?

Tags: flash

I know that flash is a great tool for web development if used in the right way. Yet for some reason it is not used on the iPad and is being phased out over many other handheld devices.

A cursory google search doesnt find any official statement as to why, and id like to know your opinion.

Comment: For some of the right reasons, and some of the wrong reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not officially being phased out on all platforms, they are simply not going to develop any future versions of Flash Player for mobile platforms.

[Read the official statement](http://blogs.adobe.com/conversations/2011/11/flash-focus.html)